# Modify Bash prompt prefix in OS X terminal

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I have a massive prompt taking my Terminal's space "*name*s-MacBook-Pro" on the same line where the command is entered on every line.

Is there a way I can remove this or make it shorter?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416274/how-to-suppress-or-customize-mac-terminal-shell-prompt

Comment: Open system preferences —> sharing, change local hostname.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/14416274/128421

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Your prompt is set by the environment variable `PS1`. This is set by the system in `/private/etc/bashrc`, but it is usually modified by the user in your dotfiles within your home directory.

Check what it is currently set as using this command:

```
echo $PS1
```

Modify it by setting the variable in your `~/.bash_profile` (or wherever you have defined it previously):

```
export PS1="$"
```

Reload the settings from your dotfiles by doing:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

This will make your new shell prompt simply a `$`

---

#### Prompt variables

- `PS1` : Primary prompt string. The default value is `\s-\v\$ .`
- `PS2` : Secondary prompt string. The default is `>`
- `PS3` : Prompt for the `select` command
- `PS4` : Printed before each command Bash displays during an execution trace. The first character of `PS4` is replicated multiple times, as necessary, to indicate multiple levels of indirection. The default is `+`

#### Syntax (from the Bash [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html))

```
\a : An ASCII bell character (07)
\d : The date in “Weekday Month Date” format (e.g., “Tue May 26”)
\D{format} : the format is passed to strftime(3) and the result is inserted into the prompt string; an empty format results in a locale-specific time representation. The braces are required
\e : An ASCII escape character (033)
\h : The hostname up to the first ‘.’
\H : The hostname
\j : The number of jobs currently managed by the shell
\l : The basename of the shell's terminal device name
\n : Newline
\r : Carriage return
\s : The name of the shell, the basename of $0 (the portion following the final slash)
\t : The current time in 24-hour HH:MM:SS format
\T : The current time in 12-hour HH:MM:SS format
\@ : The current time in 12-hour am/pm format
\A : The current time in 24-hour HH:MM format
\u : The username of the current user
\v : The version of Bash (e.g., 2.00)
\V : The release of Bash, version + patch level (e.g., 2.00.0)
\w : The current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde
\W : The basename of the current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde
\! : The history number of this command
\# : The command number of this command
\$ : If the effective UID is 0, a #, otherwise a $
\nnn : the character corresponding to the octal number nnn
\\ : A backslash
\[ : Begin a sequence of non-printing characters, which could be used to embed a terminal control sequence into the prompt
\] : end a sequence of non-printing characters
```

Comment: I wanted to keep a space between the prompt and the command I was typing, so I chose to add a space myself: `export PS1="$ "`.

Comment: David, just as a heads-up: your answer [is being discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354094/edit-original-answer-from-another-users-answer).

Comment: export PS1="$"
better to be export PS1="$ "
because that helps you differentiate between the command prompt and the actual command you’re typing in

Comment: I do export PS1="[ \u@\h:\w ]\n$ "

Comment: Just a note that the default for `PS1` for me was `\h:\W \u\$` and the default listed in this answer didn't do anything useful, they may have changed it since then

Comment: Fortunately @SubJunk, these variables can be read like any other, e.g. `echo $PS1`, `declare`, `set`...