# How to change the `$` in the terminal (Shell)

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

I'm using Mac OS X Yosmite.

[image: Terminal Window view]

I've been able to customise the colours in my terminal by pressing cmd+, when I open the terminal and change the profile options.

I've seen it before in another persons terminal window, how do I customise the `$` symbol that you see at the end? So instead of the `$` it could me something like `-.-` or whatever I wish to change it too?

Thanks!

Comment: This is set in a variable called `$PS1`. You probably have it set in your `.bashrc` or other `.bash` file

Comment: This question has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26229576/499581

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using bash, you will need to change (or set) the `PS1` variable in `.bashrc`.

Here is a tutorial: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html

Answer (score 1):

This is an example:

```
export PS1='\u@\h:\w\-.-'
```

It will change the current prompt to `username@host:working_dirctory-.-`

To make it permanent, you need to modify the `$HOME/.bashrc` file.