# bash terminal, want the cursor to be shown at the beginning of the next line

Tags: bash, macos

I use bash terminal on macos.

The user name, computer name and file path face most of the line, so if I write a long command I start on one line and continue on the next line.

Instead I would prefer the line cursor starts at the next line below user name and computer name.

```
#Current
user-mane@computer-name:~/directory/sub-directory/another-sub-directory$ls -la

#I would like to have 
user-mane@computer-name:~/directory/sub-directory/another-sub-directory$
ls -la
```

Do you have any idea, how I could start the cursor at he begining of the next line.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify Bash prompt prefix in OS X terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229576/modify-bash-prompt-prefix-in-os-x-terminal)

Comment: I think, both questions and answers are different from each other. The question you mention ask to modify shown name before the prompt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put a newline at the end of `$PS1` in the shell startup files.

Comment: I spent a lot of time prior to asking this question, but the answer is so simple :) thanks a lot. I have add following command PS1="$PS1\n" to ~/.bash_profile and restart the terminal. it worked.

Comment: I don't have `~/.bash_profile`, but i do have `~/.bashrc` though. how do i add this line there. i am using debian 11. i had other lines of code that has $PS1, so i am afraid that i may do breaking changes. here are those lines: https://pastebin.com/b1jmiSHq

Answer (score 0):

If you are having **`~/.bashrc`**, then open the file **`~/.bashrc`** and search for lines starting with **`PS1='...'`** and at the end of **`PS1='... '`** add **`\n`** like this:
**`PS1='... \n'`**

After that, save the file and exit your editor and run the command :

```
source ~/.bashrc
```