# Customizing Terminal on Mac

Tags: macos, terminal

I was wondering if there was any way to adjust how the terminal on Mac looks. Mainly, is there any way I could change the '$' after my name to be something like '>' after my name. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to suppress (or customize) Mac Terminal shell prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416274/how-to-suppress-or-customize-mac-terminal-shell-prompt)

Answer (score 0):

To get a non-permanent preview you can just do

```
export PS1=">"
```

To make this permanent add this command to your .bash_profile.

To add the date, directory or other information, you can add any of the following to the text inside the quotes after PS1=       :

\d – Current date

\t – Current time

\h – Host name

# – Command number

\u – User name

\W – Current working directory

\w – Current working directory with full path